# Target iframe and access its content to target a class with javascript

Tags: javascript

Inside my Html i inserted an Iframe Tag to embed another document within the current HTML document.
Inside this Iframe i have a Form.

```
<!--------------------MODAL------------------------------ -->
<!--------------------JqueryForm------------------------------ -->
<iframe 
  src="Checkout/form.html" scrolling="yes" id="checkout"
  style="min-width:280px;width:100%;height:600px;border:none;"
  frameborder="none" 
  allowTransparency="true" >
</iframe>
<!-- ----------------------------------------------- -->
```

Inside this Form i want to target a `Button` with the class of `stripe_button` and the code looks like this

```
<div class="form-group f28  jf-hide" data-fid="f28">
    <label class="control-label" for="f28"></label>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg stripe_button" style="z-index: 1;">
      <span class="fa fa-credit-card-alt" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      Stripe
    </button>
    <div class="form-group"><img src="https://stripe.com/img/about/logos/badge/solid-dark.svg"></div>
    
  </div>
```

I do this with the following Javascript `code`

```
// target iframe inside index.ejs
    var iframe = document.getElementById('checkout');
// get iframe content
    var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
// targeting class and awaiting click event to run function
    innerDoc.getElementsByClassName('stripe_button')[0].addEventListener('click', purchaseClicked)
```

As for my understanding everything should be working correctly but i still get an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined` at this part
`innerDoc.getElementsByClassName('stripe_button')[0].addEventListener('click', purchaseClicked)`

This means im not targeting the `contentDocument` body properly.

Comment: innerDoc.getElementsByClassName('stripe_button')[0] is not defined. But you're trying to add a listener to it. Did you try console.log(innerDoc) or console.log( innerDoc.getElementsByClassName('stripe_button'))?

Comment: @mkaatman The point is "why is it not defined"

Comment: is the iframe loaded yet? you can put an event listener on the load event of the iframe and then run your code in there

Comment: Thanks @mkaatman i forgot to define it first. i went along with `var stripe = innerDoc.getElementsByClassName('stripe_button')
    for (var i = 0; i < stripe.length; i++) {
        var stripe_button = stripe[i]
        stripe_button.addEventListener('click', purchaseClicked)
    }`

Comment: @chiliNUT yes im loading through ready function `if (document.readyState == 'loading') {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ready)
} else {
    ready()
}`

Comment: ready state could be `interactive` or `loading`